# Scrolleft not working in firefox

Tags: jquery

The following works in internet explorer, and chrome but not in firefox and I wonder why (The elements with class .absolutePos is not moving).

```
    $("#eTable_body").scroll(function() {
        $('.absolutePos').css('left', $('#eTable_body').scrollLeft() + 'px');
        console.log($('#eTable_body').scrollLeft());
    });
```

It prints out in Firefox: the scrolleft so that also works but it won't move the .absolutePos elements on screen. I have position relative on the class bellow and If I change it to position absolute it works but then it looks ugly so I prefer not to change the position of the class. Is there anything else I can do in order to make it work in firefox?

```
.absolutePos{
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

**EDIT**

The below fiddle is a simplified version. If you test it in chrome you will see that the class will move but it wont move in firefox. Now I can't have position absolute on the class "absolutePos". So my question is, is there anything else I can do to make it work in firefox?
http://jsfiddle.net/YMvk9/4902/

Comment: Please post your html.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML code and also a little explanation as to what it is you're trying to achieve? Sometimes knowing what you're trying to build helps us find solutions.

Comment: I added a fiddle to explain what I mean =)

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but my rep is too small for that.
Change the css of your **.headcol** as follows:

```
.headcol {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border-width: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    zIndex: 2; /* more only if you really need that */
}
```

This works in all browsers, but: **"Don't ask me why!"**